# Nested Bootstrap tables not filling parent cell height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, nested-table

Okay so I have some fairly complex HTML, and my main issue is that I can't seem to get the height of the nested tables to match their parent cells' height. I have tried using `height: 100%` but it doesn't work. Here is a js fiddle of my code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/214rcuwd/

The nested tables are in the "Tasks to be performed: section. Also note this is temporary, I will be removing most of the style attributes and adding css classes eventually. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.table {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/214rcuwd/1/)**

Comment: Worked like a charm, nobody mentioned that in any of the other posts I read!